# SQLite problem deleting element from table

Tags: android, sqlite

for some reason I can't delete a row of my table, this is my simple database:

```
create table party(_id integer primary key autoincrement, dateID text not null, partyName text not null, eventDate text not null, eventID text not null)
```

and I wrote a method to delete a party knowing the dateID

```
public boolean deletePartyFromDateId(String dateID) 
{
    boolean result = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_DATEID + "=" + dateID, null) > 0;
    return result;    
}
```

**I also wrote a simple method to delete all the elements, and this works fine**

```
public boolean deleteAll() 
{
    boolean result = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null) > 0;
    return result;    
}
```

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Can you post the exception/error log?

Comment: just curious, did you check if the column name is spelt correct. from hear you are not using **KEY_DATEID** in the **create** statment.

Comment: Thank you guys! @Jack 08-03 19:29:36.319: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8492): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "70d1f4": , while compiling: DELETE FROM party WHERE dateID LIKE 70d1f4    * Sam Quest, yes the spelling is correct :)

Comment: You can edit your original post and insert it at the bottom :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you shoud try this

```
boolean result = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_DATEID + "='" + dateID+"'", null) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean result = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_DATEID + "=?", new String[]{dateID}) > 0;
return result;
```

try this.

Comment: Hei thanks, the code is working but not perfectly, sometimes doesn't delete the correct "party", I need to check better my database elements before I can mark your answer as correct. Thank you :)